# Vue loading data with async await I get post.likes is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am loading data from a back end using axios with async await:

```
onBeforeMount(async () => {
    const feed = await axios.get("api/v1/posts/" + loggedUser + "/home/feed/");
    feed.data.sort((a, b) => (a.created_at > b.created_at ? 1 : -1));
    homefeed.value = feed.data;
    filtered.value = feed.data;
});
```

I have this function to make a user like a post and unlike a post. It must show the one image if it is liked by a user and another image if it's not yet liked by this user.

I get an error post.likes is undefined if I do not add v-if="post.likes" to the containing div. If I do add it to the containing div then no error and on the posts that do have likes it displays correctly, but on the posts that do not have likes it does not display at all so the user is unable to like the post

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="postLike flex alignCenter" v-if="post.likes">
    <div class="postLikeImg" @click="likePost">
        <img
            class="functionImg mr5"
            alt="Like this post"
            src="../assets/img/like.png"
            @click="likePost"
            v-if="post.likes[0] != true"
        />
        <img
            class="functionImg mr5"
            alt="Like this post"
            src="../assets/img/liked.png"
            @click="unlikePost"
            v-if="post.likes[0] == true"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="postStatsBtn likeTotal">
        {{ post.likes[1] }}
    </div>
</div>
```

The button need to display even if there are no likes for the post so how do I get past the post.likes is undefined please?

Why am I getting the error if I load the data with async await?

Comment: Sounds like some of your `posts` data does not have a `likes` property, or it is not an array, in which case `post.likes[0]` will cause an error.

Comment: Yes I found the issue sometimes my brain is in my foot. Do I delete this question or what should I do?

Comment: No worries lol. Most people just leave their questions, but I guess there isn't much reason to keep this one up, so closing it or deleting is probably a good idea